# Python sum of associated numbers in a list for a given name

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
d = {'a': ['Adam', 'Book', 4], 'b': ['Bill', 'TV', 6, 'Jill', 'Sports', 1, 'Bill', 'Computer', 5], 'c': ['Bill', 'Sports', 3], 'd': ['Quin', 'Computer', 3, 'Adam', 'TV', 3], 'e': ['Quin', 'TV', 2, 'Quin', 'Book', 5], 'f': ['Adam', 'Computer', 7]}
```

Each list represents the amount of times the person uses the given object. For example, for list 'a', it shows that `Adam` reads a `Book` `4` times a week. In 'b', `Bill` watches `TV` `6` times a week and '`Jill`' plays `sports` once a week.

I want to find the total number of times a person does something, within each list.

The output, in this case, would be something like this:

```
a: Adam 4
b: Bill 11, Jill 1
c: Bill 3
d: Quin 3, Adam 3
e: Quin 7
f: Adam 7
```

Doesn't have to be that exact format, but something like that.

Currently, I've tried using Counter but that counts only the peoples names, not the numbers associated with it. I have tried just returning the names and then the numbers, but that doesn't end up working for lists that have more than 1 name, as some have even 6 total names.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This is a very unusual way to store this data. How was it generated?

Comment: @Maulwurfn: user1530318 answered that, saying he used Counter.

Comment: Where does this strange data format come from? Can't you use a *reasonable* data structure?

Comment: FWIW -- I don't see how this is a bad question.  The user provides good input, and (reasonably) clearly states what the desired output is.  Also the user hints at at attempt using a `Counter`.  The question doesn't deserve downvotes just because the data-structure is a little obscure (IMHO).

Comment: Sorry, not a super computer science-y person, using this as it is something I have experience with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this with your data structure, you could do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

for k, lst in d.iteritems():
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(0, len(lst), 3):
        counts[lst[i]] += lst[i + 2]
    print k, ", ".join(["%s %d" % (n, c) for n, c in counts.items()])
```

*However*, a better idea would be to store the data in a sensible data structure. Storing information in lists with rules like "Each list comes in groups of threes, where the first of each three is the name etc" makes working with the data clumsy and counterintuitive. Instead, what if you stored the data as:

```
d = {'a': {'Adam': {'Book': 4}},
     'b': {'Bill': {'TV': 6, 'Computer': 5}, 'Jill': {'Sports': 1}},
     'c': {'Bill': {'Sports': 3}},
     'd': {'Quin': {'Computer': 3}, 'Adam': {'TV': 3}},
     'e': {'Quin': {'TV': 2, 'Book': 5}},
     'f': {'Adam': {'Computer': 7}}}
```

Then, you could answer the question like this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print k, ", ".join(["%s %d" % (n, sum(a.values())) for n, a in v.items()])
```

This would have many other benefits as well: You could find out how many times Adam read a book in "a" just by doing `d["a"]["Adam"]["Book"]` (or, if you're not sure that "Adam" or "Book" are there, `d["a"].get("Adam", {}).get("Book", 0)`). Other calculations based on this list would also be possible and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I Will look more into this reasonable data structure

Answer (score 2):

I think that a `defaultdict` and list slicing would be useful here ...

```
a = ['Adam', 'TV', 4, 'Adam', 'Bike', 4 ]
print a[::3] # ['Adam', 'Adam' ]
print a[2::3] # [4, 4]

from collections import defaultdict
for key,value in d.items():
    c = defaultdict(int)
    for k,v in zip(value[::3],value[2::3]):
        c[k] += v
    print key, c
```

A `Counter` would work too, but it's not introduced until python2.7 whereas `defaultdict` is python2.5 compatible and provides the same functionality in this instance.

Although as others have stated, this seems to be a *very strange* data structure that you're using ...

Comment: @user1530318 -- Always happy to help.  Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired result:

```
import collections
for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems()):
        tmp=collections.defaultdict(int)
        for i in xrange(0, len(v), 3):
                tmp[v[i]]+=v[i+2]
        print "{}: {}".format(k,
                ", ".join("%s %s" % (a, b)
                        for a, b in sorted(tmp.iteritems())))
```

Output:

```
a: Adam 4
b: Bill 11, Jill 1
c: Bill 3
d: Adam 3, Quin 3
e: Quin 7
f: Adam 7
```